# Ghost recon phantom

Tags: ghost-recon-phantoms

I am new to Tom Clancy's ghost recon phantom. When I try to install the game, it shows "error in patching"
I have tried to uninstall the game and delete /appdata/apps folder, but still no luck.

Any solutions?

I have a GeForce GT750m GDDR5 2gb GPU.

Comment: Is there any further details on the error?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have try to install the game through Steam, and it works.